# Alternative method to get user likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I have a canvas application that implement with a like gate as most of other applications. Unlike tab page application,  to check whether user liked a fanpage, it requires user_likes permission, but my submission on user_likes was rejected several times. And below is the reply from the review team.

"Your request for user_likes permissions to see if a user has liked your page does not enhance a user's experience in the app and thus doesn't meet our utility guidelines. As an app developer, you can already see who has liked your page. Please do not resubmit for the user_likes permission. Please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0 for more information about permissions."

Since they mentioned "As an app developer, you can already see who has liked your page."

I tested using a fan access token to request me/likes and FQL SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=XXX, both return an empty array.

The results of using app token or page access token are also the same.

So I'm wandering if there any other method to tell whether a user has liked a page.

UPDATE : I'd killed all my like-gating, and informed my client that only can be done on tab page app now. Although my client still asking why FB encourages we incentivize a user for liking our page, but doesn't provide a method for us to do so ? (https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse )

@Wizkid, is that alright that we treat your reply as an official reply from FB ? We're going show this thread to the client, so they know this cannot be done.

Comment: WizKid, You are not really answering the question.
Since the review team mentioned "As an app developer, you can already see who has liked your page.". I am asking about the method.
Please at least read the question.

Comment: You asked if there was any other method to tell if the user have liked a page. And there isn't so I answered with a no. What should I have answered. I should have lied and said that it is possible?

Comment: So, you mean the FB Review team lied to me?

Comment: What do you mean that they lied?

Comment: "As an app developer, you can already see who has liked your page."
This is what they replied.

Comment: I have no idea what they mean with that or in which context that was said. The only way that can be true is if they meant in page tab apps and that you are already aware of

Comment: Yes, at the beginning I believe they mistreated my app as an page tap app. But since there quite a number of "undocumented" methods on facebook platform, and I am using some of them. That's why I made this question and hope to find out if anyone in the community know alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue here. Is like-gating against FB policies now? We offer a fan-only content and clearly like-gating is enhancing the experience.

Answers given from the FB review team are not clear enough. Could someone explain what

"As an app developer, you can already see who has liked your page."

actually means?

UPDATE:
I read on Facebook Developers group that Facebook will not let you get through review for user_likes if the purpose is simple like gating.